# n-sphere surface by induction

Tags: integration, geometry, induction, surfaces, spheres

I try to calculate the surface of an n-sphere by induction. For a sphere of radius $r$ in $n$ dimensions the surface should be:
$$S_{n-1}(r)=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}r^{n-1}$$

So I think I should be able to calculate it is by taking all possible choices for spheres with one dimension less:
$$S_{n-1}(r)=\int_{-r}^r dx S_{n-2}(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})$$

Let's try:
$$\int_{-r}^r dx \frac{2\pi^{n/2-1/2}}{\Gamma(n/2-1/2)}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}^{n-2}=\frac{2\pi^{n/2-1/2}}{\Gamma(n/2-1/2)}r^{n-1}\int_{-1}^1 dy \sqrt{1^2-y^2}^{n-2}$$

by change of variable $x=ry$,$dx=rdy$. So far looks good. Let's evaluate the integral using [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function) using another change $y=\sqrt{t}$ $dy=t^{-1/2}/2$:
$$\int_{-1}^1 dy \sqrt{1^2-y^2}^{n-2}=\int_{0}^{1}dtt^{-1/2}\left(1-t\right)^{\left(n-2\right)/2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma(n/2+1/2)}$$

so I don't get the correct result...

Comment: You want to think about the volume form of an $(n-2)$-sphere.

Comment: Basically, the change of variable formula you employed is a generalization of something and you need to think about what that is.

Comment: Why think about the volume of an $(n-2)$ sphere? @Blue1.644934, can you elaborate?

Comment: I was just trying to lead you in another more enlightening(?) direction, but your problem stems from how you set up your integral. Try using polar coordinates from the beginning.

Comment: I have to go to bed, but fundamentally, even if your integral was set up properly, $S_{n-1} $ is tied to the volume $V_{n} $. Calculating the integral over $S_{n-2}$ yields the volume $V_{n-1}$ not the surface area.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above derivation is using the wrong measure on $x\in[-r,r]$. Using the correct measure:
$$S_{n-1}(r)=\int_{-r}^r \frac{r dx}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} S_{n-2}(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})$$

This measure is derived using polar coordinates where $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$; in this representation $x=r\sin\theta$, $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}=r cos\theta$ and $dx=r \cos\theta d\theta$.

Now we have:
$$\int_{-r}^r \frac{r dx}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} \frac{2\pi^{n/2-1/2}}{\Gamma(n/2-1/2)}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}^{n-2}=\frac{2\pi^{n/2-1/2}}{\Gamma(n/2-1/2)}r^{n-1}\int_{-1}^1 dy \sqrt{1^2-y^2}^{n-3}$$

by change of variable $x=ry$,$dx=rdy$. Let's evaluate the integral using [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) using another change $y=\sqrt{t}$ $dy=t^{-1/2}/2$:
$$\int_{-1}^1 dy \sqrt{1^2-y^2}^{n-3}=\int_{0}^{1}dtt^{-1/2}\left(1-t\right)^{\left(n-3\right)/2}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(n/2-1/2)}{\Gamma(n/2)}$$

so that collecting all the terms we have the wanted result.